# Loading JSON file from github for Google Sheet

Tags: python

I am trying to use a google service account to link py script to google sheet. I have a working py script. However, I want to share the script to my clients so I have created a repository in github with the credentials (JSON file) also uploaded in the repository. I need to load the JSON file in the python script directly from the github so that every one with the script can have a universal access to JSON as well.

**Currently the code looks like this**

```
import requests
import gspread
from gspread_formatting import *

gc = gspread.service_account(filename="C:\\bin\\myjson.json")
```

**Can it be changed to something like:**

```
json_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/main/myjson.json'
f = requests.get(json_url)
json_name = json.loads(f.text)
gc = gspread.service_account(filename=json_name)
```

**type of json**

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "theta-*****-303113",
  "private_key_id": "00ff078a8042c*********d8db217c39a5f5",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQClYkjapoOA7nBy\n1kiyK08i8J3zIRiScH784rMxik6nHJKFftT3pg3wfEvsN4UowZf73PL5gvm3ZJc8\nocoXNnHPvvJd+pFdk7w7qmwBgGeDT4PSN7Clu9YW5OPfr4Wj27eMAhQzt+/CpLRK\nroU6P7I82yhkh4ihIDzS6xh6c40nEB2cW***************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\nCn2ciEfhwJZyN+u/Fgm4nYa+\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "g-service-acc@theta-*****-303113.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "10767932****790042565",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/g-service-acc%40theta-trees-303113.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Comment: If these credentials are real then you shouldn't keep them public. Right now they are available for everyone to see.

Comment: Could you share the json format? Meaning the keys and the types of the values that you are expecting.

Comment: yes. i have added to the edits

Comment: @kulekhain Again, you shouldn't include the private values that you're using in the json. You can just specify the type of the value

Comment: yes. being aware of that, I have actually put *** and randomized the original values. So the values of the keys are kind of arbitrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save your json data into a file like so:

```
json_url = 'https://someurl.com'
filename = 'credentials.json'
res = requests.get(json_url)
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(res.text)  # save the data into a file
gc = gspread.service_account(filename=filename)
```

If you don't want to save the file locally to your machine, you can do something like this:

```
json_url = 'https://someurl.com'
filename = 'credentials.json'
res = requests.get(json_url)
credentials = res.json()
gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(credentials)
```

Comment: thanks. that works. but ideally, I was thinking of accessing the json directly from github rather than having it saved to a local machine. Ultimately, my goal is to run it on heroku server - so, would saving the file 'credentials.json' also work in remote server?

OR 

storing the contents of json in the variable within the script would also work for my purpose (in case if its possible). But i am not sure how to do that :(

Comment: as per the docs, you could use `service_account_from_dict`